# Reload a Data Grid based on back end API response Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

Am new in Angular technology and working with Angular with spring boot as back end. Am stuck in reloading data gird.i have a backed API call for populating data gird. My issue was like some time data will change in the response.based on this I need to update my data grid in UI.

**Edit 1**

**Angular.ts file**

```
@ViewChild('modal', { static: false }) modal;

  columns = [
    {
      prop: 'Name',
      name: 'name'
    },
    {
      prop: 'Location',
      name: 'Location'
    },
    {
      prop: 'Status',
      name: 'Status'
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  getData(name): Observable<Nodes> {
    return this.service.getData(name).pipe(map((data) => {
      return data;
    }));
  }

  loadInitialData() {
this.getData(this.name).subscribe((data) => {
  this.dataFrom = data;
  this.service.saveMessage(data);

  data.dataNodes.forEach((elm) => {
    if (elm.archiveGroups === null) {
      return;
    }

    elm.archiveGroups.forEach(arch => {
      if (arch.archives === null) {
        return;
      }
      let row: rowJson;
      arch.archives.forEach(arc => {
        row = Object.assign(new rowJson(), {
          Name: arc.Name,
          Location: elm.NodeName,             
          Status: arc.status,
        });
        this.rows.push(row)
      });
    });
  });
  this.loadingState = false;
  this.populateData();
}, err => {
  
});
```

}

**Edit 2**

I have done below changes in ngOnInit method.but status filed not updated

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.updateSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(
        (val) => { 
            
            this.getData(this.hostname).subscribe((data) => {
                data.dataNodes.forEach((elm) => {          
                    elm.archiveGroups.forEach(arch => {
                      if (arch.archives === null) {
                        return;
                      }
                      arch.archives.forEach(arc => {
                        let row: rowJson;
                          row.Status=arc.status                        
                      });
                    });
                  });
            });
      }
    );
  }
```

How to update status field based on **getData** **API** response.I could see a lot of queries regarding reload. Please guide and suggest a valid Solution

Comment: which grid are you using and do you want to reload the entire grid or change only a  specific column or cell?

Comment: can you update code to valid first? Where calls loadInitalData()?What is abc.data?

Comment: i need to update status column

Comment: @huan feng updated the code

Comment: What's the method to refresh the grid? is it loadInitialData? If yes, you should always return the new reference instead of using forEach on the origin data.

Comment: I need to implement the refresh logic.what are the way to do refresh.